# can we close a case in before trigger? Case status still show Open

Tags: apex, before-trigger

```
trigger caseClose on Case (before insert) {
    list<case> cases= new list<case>();
    Id caseRecordtypeId = SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('abc').getRecordTypeId();
    for(case c:trigger.new){
    system.debug('recordtypeid: '+c.RecordTypeId);
        if(c.RecordTypeId == caseRecordtypeId && c.Reason=='aaa' && c.Case_Sub_Reason__c=='bbb'){
            case caseObj=new case();
            caseObj.Status='Closed';
            cases.add(caseObj);
        }
    }
    insert cases;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're literally creating new cases when your conditions are met. Instead, just update the records in Trigger.new:

```
for(case c:trigger.new){
    system.debug('recordtypeid: '+c.RecordTypeId);
    if(c.RecordTypeId == caseRecordtypeId && c.Reason=='aaa' && c.Case_Sub_Reason__c=='bbb'){
        c.Status='Closed';
    }
}
```

No DML operation is needed when using before insert or before update, and you update the values in Trigger.new. Any changes made to this collection will be committed when the trigger ends.